# Cypress redirect to another url on click of logout is timing out

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

Here is the scenario:

I'm logging to my application by visiting app.domain/login (example) which will redirect me to something like another.app.domain/ 
This is working fine. But when I logout:  `cy.contains('logout').click()`, I am getting

*CypressError: Timed out after waiting '60000ms' for your remote page to load.*

Any suggestions to get around this issue? Ps: I just started to learn Cypress and I want to logout mainly because I want to restore the state back.. I don't want my environment to be updated/modified with the automation scripts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you logged correctly, but logout method fails, right?

Comment: @Przemyslaw Jan Beigert. Yes logged in, but unable to log out

Comment: Pls add all test file, to answer and mark line where test fails

Comment: Basically I want to cleat all the changes done by automation scripts in QA environment. Ex: I have created a user through automation and while logging in in my QA env, I still see the user created through the automated scripts. Sorry, I won't be able to share the test file due to privacy issues. I tried to make the post so generic. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So maybe cypress is not needed, just do your test on cypress and clean up via api calls from `curl`?

Comment: Isn't it possible in cypress?

Comment: It is, however we can reach goal with more simple tools, instead of running cypress we can call one bash script e.g `curl "url1" && curl "url2"`. Should be faster and more stable. If you're interested in I can prepare some bash script as a example.

Comment: Yes I am! Please provide more details. and if possible, How to do it from Cypress?

Comment: check my answer and let me know what about authentication

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in cypress there is no `AfterAll` hook, so we have to use more handmade solution. Second think: if you want to use cypress instead of curl to clean up after test is ok (but I recommend us `curl` ;)).

First you need to add line to scripts section in `package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "after-cypress": "cypress run --spec cypress/hooks/after-all.js",

  }
}
```

File `cypress/hooks/after-all.js` should looks like this:

```js
describe('clean up after test', () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.login() // Should we save auth token here?
  });

  it('', () => {
   cy
      .request() 
      .request()
      .request() // each of request should delete created during test data

  });

});
```

Comment: So, I have to create requests to delete all the data right?

Comment: Check maybe there already exist, so you can just call it from `cy.request()` command.